# Could not find a declaration file for module, but not using Tyepscript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, module

I have created a package of React components that I am now trying to use inside a React app bootstrapped with create-react-app, but I am encountering this issue.

[image]

I have looked around and it seems that this is related to Typescript, but I am not using Typescript at all.
What am I missing?

Comment: If you get that error you ***are*** using typescript. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] (codesandbox allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) local projects via CLI). Simplest way to make it go away would be to create a `types.d.ts` file in root containing `declare module "components-lib-three"`

Comment: @tao, thanks, this solved the issue. Create-react-app uses Typescript indeed, I did not notice.